# in StringBuffer i want to add half bold text and half normal in append

Tags: android, html, stringbuffer

how can i set half bold text by html.fromhtml i try but didn't work in append of BufferString out append its work fine please help me here is code

```
String amt = "AMOUNT: ";
                Spanned tyyy =Html.fromHtml("<b>"+"TYPE: "+"</b>");
                String Dat = "DATE: ";
                String des = "DESCRIPTION: ";

                buffer.append(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+amt+"</b>"+"<small>"+cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex("AMOUNT"))+"</small>")+"\n");
                buffer.append(tyyy+cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex("TYPE"))+"\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be from HTML, you can use `SpannableStringBuilder`:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.append("TYPE:");
// bold the current text
int boldStartIndex = 0;
int boldEndIndex = bulder.length();
builder.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeace.BOLD, boldStartIndex, boldEndIndex, Spanned.FLAG_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE));
// append the rest, it will not be bolded
builder.append("the-rest-of-your-data");
```

You can then set the builder directly to a TextView via `TextView.setText(builder);`. This may be a better approach than using HTML, as HTML tags support isn't very well documented and may not be supported across various devices.